# How to check length of Tstringlist in delphi

Tags: delphi

This is what I am trying to do.  I have a Tstringlist, for a name.  If the name is in a format DOE, JOHN, NMI, I want it to split the name into 3 different strings.
But the problem is, what if there is no middle initial.  Or First name.  Like it could be just DOE,   Then the last two lines are out of bounds.  And the program crashes.  What is the best solution?

```
var ptname, physname: Tstringlist;

if pos(',',Msg.Grp2[0].ObsReq[0].OrderingProviderFamilyName) > 0 then // split it if it has a comma
begin
  physname := TstringList.Create;
  physname.CommaText := Msg.Grp2[0].ObsReq[0].OrderingProviderFamilyName;
  Parameters.ParamByName('@OrderingLastNameOBR16').Value := physname[0];
  Parameters.ParamByName('@OrderingFirstNameOBR16').Value := physname[1];
  Parameters.ParamByName('@OrderingMiddleNameOBR16').Value := physname[2];
  physname.Free;
end
```

Comment: David's good solution aside, it would be cleaner to have a fully-populated CSV. If an element is missing, you just have commas.
ex: DOE would be DOE,,   Then it still splits ok without having to mess around.

Comment: @Chris: David?  David who? Harumph! :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `TStringList.Count`.

```
  physname := TstringList.Create;
  physname.CommaText := Msg.Grp2[0].ObsReq[0].OrderingProviderFamilyName;
  if physname.Count > 0 then
  begin
    Parameters.ParamByName('@OrderingLastNameOBR16').Value := physname[0];
    if physname.Count > 1 then
    begin
      Parameters.ParamByName('@OrderingFirstNameOBR16').Value := physname[1];
      if physname.Count > 2 then
      begin
        Parameters.ParamByName('@OrderingMiddleNameOBR16').Value := physname[2];
      end;
    end;
  end;
  physname.Free;
```